# $A \subseteq B \iff A \cap B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Is it true that $A \subseteq B \iff A \cap B = A$? Is this is always correct? Where I can find a proof? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct and the proof is straightforward:

$\implies$: $A \cap B \subseteq A$ is trivial. If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, by hypothesis. So $x \in A \cap B$ and $A \subseteq A \cap B$.

$\impliedby$: We have $A = A \cap B \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A\subseteq B$ and let $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$, therefore $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Conversely, let $x\in A$, since $A\subseteq B$, $x\in B$ and $x\in A\cap B$, therefore $A\subseteq A\cap B$. Finally, one has: $A\cap B=A$.

Assume $A\cap B=A$, let $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\in B$. Therefore, $A\subseteq B$.